# Deployed Next.js Project on Vercel: Fetching Data from Localhost API Endpoint Issue

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

I've recently deployed my full-stack Next.js project on Vercel, which includes an API endpoint located within the local development environment. While the project functions flawlessly on my local setup using localhost:3000 to fetch data, I've encountered a challenge after deployment on Vercel.

In my code, I've been utilizing process.env.NEXT_AUTH_URL to call the API endpoint, which has been set to localhost:3000 for local development. However, I've realized that this setup won't function once deployed on Vercel, as it doesn't have access to the local environment.

I'm seeking guidance on how to adapt my code to ensure it successfully fetches data from my database while the project is live on Vercel.

A sample code from my project:

```
async function getData() {
  const apiEndpoint = process.env.NEXT_AUTH_URL;

  const res = await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}api/posts`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}
```

I also tried to remove the apiendpoint and keep it without that as both are running on same port like :

```
const res = await fetch(`/api/posts`)
```

but that doesn't  worked neither in local environment nor in vercel

`File structure (Image link as I don't have 10 points yet):` https://i.ibb.co/fkgd5Pn/image.png

Any insights, code snippets, or best practices on how to dynamically handle API endpoint URLs for both local development and deployment on Vercel would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
async function getData() {
  const apiEndpoint = process.env.NEXT_AUTH_URL;

  const res = await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}api/posts`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return res.json();
}
```

if you use this function in client component ,await fetch(`/api/posts`),this way also work, but it is user component you should declared as

```
 await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}api/posts`)
```

this way,

another thing is , if that component is server component , you can directly use env file variable this way ,

```
 process.env.NEXT_AUTH_URL
```

but it is client component , you can only have a access to the variable that has define ,

NEXT_PUBLIC_....

this way

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand where your database will be deployed in production. See [Vercel's guidance on databases](https://vercel.com/guides/using-databases-with-vercel) for more information. While you can use a local database in development on your local host, you must run a database server somewhere such that your Next application can access it when deployed on Vercel. This could be on Vercel itself, or on a different cloud provider like AWS, GCP, etc.

Secondly, I am assuming this is a client-side fetch (otherwise you should fetch the data directly on the server without going through `/api`). You should be able to simply `fetch('/api/posts')`. Please add the specific error you're getting so we can help you troubleshoot why that relative path isn't working.

Lastly, since you are deploying on Vercel, you [do not need to specify `NEXT_AUTH_URL` yourself](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url):

> Using System Environment Variables we automatically detect when you deploy to Vercel so you don't have to define this variable. Make sure Automatically expose System Environment Variables is checked in your Project Settings.

Comment: @argo
I am using src directory and inside that I have a app folder and inside that I have my api folder and inside that api folder I have another folder know as posts and inside that I have a route.ts file from where I want to fetch data and show into my page.tsx folder which is inside the blog folder and the blog folder is also inside the app folder:

in short:
```from: src/app/api/posts/route.ts ```
```to: src/app/blog/page.tsx```

and for database I am using MongoDB cluster

Comment: You will need to dynamically configure parts of your application (such as your database address) using [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) such that once deployed, your application does not attempt to access `localhost`. For your API calls, you can achieve this by using relative URLs. For the database, you will want to feed the database connection URL as an environment variable.

Comment: I already did that

Comment: In which case, "Please add the specific error you're getting so we can help you troubleshoot why that relative path isn't working."

Comment: the error is it can't find the api end point as I am using localhost:3000 so error is  obvious and if I don't use the localhost only use the `/api/posts` then it can't find the api.
And the vercel error is also same.
actually I was sick so I was offline, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Please paste the exact error message. You mention "I am using localhost:3000", but I don't see that configured anywhere in your code snippet. Please add the code snippet that references localhost.